# In the preview, the number of dollar signs doubles every time a formula is used

Tags: bug, status-completed, mathjax

On Chrome and Firefox under Ubuntu, I get the following strange behavior:
[image]

Comment: I get something similar (with Firefox on Ubuntu), except the exponentially growing dollar signs don't appear on separate lines. Also, scrolling appears to prompt it to display a bunch of script $x$'s with large spaces in between.

Comment: @Akhil: Markdown will respect newlines if you have two spaces before the line break, which is what I did to generate this example.

Comment: I'm seeing this on Firefox 3.6 under both Fedora and Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed.

Twas a bug on a compatibility patch (IE handles javascript regex a little differently than... any other browser [arguably more sanely, but still differently]) that caused the number of escaped `$`s to double for each identical `$string$` in a post (in anything other than IE).